# Опять браузеры, и опять совместимость. Или просто, современная тенденция ...

Tags: браузер

Натолкнули на размышления вот эти данные. [Клаць](http://html5test.com/results.html)

Если говорить проще, у меня появилась мысль о том, что с такими темпами, и таким подходом, современному интернету грозит одно простое правило. Нечего соваться в интернет со старым браузером. Согласитесь, уже не очень смешо и забавно заботиться о совместимости с ИЕ 6,7,8,9 в то время как уже на тебе 10. Опера, хром, фф, двигаются еще более динамично.

Какие будут прогнозы на ближайшее будущее в плане обратной совместимости?

Comment: все зависит от задач, смотря на какую аудиторию рассчитываешь, я про то, что, например, есть компании, у которых стоит лицензионный софт, там там до-сих-пор стоит ИЕ6, ну или аудитория - домохозяек, которые пользуются в основном ИЕ, ну или проекты типа фейсбука или ВК - тебе бы хотелось что бы там писало - "работает только под последней версией мозилы", зато все очень красиво =) потому обратная совместимость всегда будет иметь место, все зависит только от "длинны" этой совместимости и политики браузеров

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 это все сведет во едино

Comment: Вы оптимист! Тоже очень на это надеюсь ...